# No demand for Commercial zones

Tags: simcity-4

None of my cities are showing any demand for commercial development. I zone them at all three levels but none ever progress. This is a recent problem after coming back to the game after a three month break - when I played before commercial zones always developed. I have even adjusted tax to low levels to try and entice shops, offices etc. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to:
http://strategywiki.org/wiki/SimCity_4/Zoning_and_Demand#Commercial

Having more neighbor connections is your best bet, as well as building up means of transportation like airports and railroads.

Otherwise, I would make sure you have a balanced demand for other zones as well. Maybe you need to increase population and/or industry.